# Project fails in debug mode, but works in release mode

Tags: visual-c++

My project works well in release mode, but it can not run in debug mode. I search many references, but the problem can not be solved. Here is the output. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: StreamWFSTComService20130614s2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>atlsd.lib(atlfuncs.obj) : error LNK2005: "long __cdecl ATL::AtlComModuleRegisterClassObjects(struct ATL::_ATL_COM_MODULE70 *,unsigned long,unsigned long)" (?AtlComModuleRegisterClassObjects@ATL@@YAJPEAU_ATL_COM_MODULE70@1@KK@Z) already defined in StreamWFSTComService20130606.obj
1>atlsd.lib(atlfuncs.obj) : error LNK2005: "long __cdecl ATL::AtlComModuleRevokeClassObjects(struct ATL::_ATL_COM_MODULE70 *)" (?AtlComModuleRevokeClassObjects@ATL@@YAJPEAU_ATL_COM_MODULE70@1@@Z) already defined in StreamWFSTComService20130606.obj
1>atlsd.lib(atlfuncs.obj) : error LNK2005: "long __cdecl ATL::AtlInternalQueryInterface(void *,struct ATL::_ATL_INTMAP_ENTRY const *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)" (?AtlInternalQueryInterface@ATL@@YAJPEAXPEBU_ATL_INTMAP_ENTRY@1@AEBU_GUID@@PEAPEAX@Z) already defined in WFSTCOMService.obj
1>atlsd.lib(atlfuncs.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl ATL::AtlCallTermFunc(struct ATL::_ATL_MODULE70 *)" (?AtlCallTermFunc@ATL@@YAXPEAU_ATL_MODULE70@1@@Z) already defined in StreamWFSTComService20130606.obj
1>atlsd.lib(atlfuncs.obj) : error LNK2005: "long __cdecl ATL::AtlModuleAddTermFunc(struct ATL::_ATL_MODULE70 *,void (__cdecl*)(unsigned __int64),unsigned __int64)" (?AtlModuleAddTermFunc@ATL@@YAJPEAU_ATL_MODULE70@1@P6AX_K@Z1@Z) already defined in WFSTCOMService.obj
1>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\StreamWFSTComService20130918_2\StreamWFSTComService20130918\Debug\StreamWFSTComService20130614s2.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
2>------ Build started: Project: TestSTTCom, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1137,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Windows\SysWOW64\StreamWFSTComService20130918_2\StreamWFSTComService20130918\FST\TestSTTCom\.\Debug\TestSTTCom.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\StreamWFSTComService20130918_2\StreamWFSTComService20130918\StreamWFSTComService20130918\Debug\TestSTT.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1139,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(TestSTTCom) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (TestSTT). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
2>  TestSTT.vcxproj -> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\StreamWFSTComService20130918_2\StreamWFSTComService20130918\FST\TestSTTCom\.\Debug\TestSTTCom.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You have both the debug and the release versions of some object files or libraries included in your debug build. You need to use only one of them (debug or release) depending on the target you're building.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I am a beginner. Can you tell me how to check the debug and the release versions of the object files or libraries? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Studio, you can check it in your project properties by choosing your project then press alt-enter, then you can go to menu debug to configure to "debug"